# Grouping Data in R with a new Column Name

Tags: r, grouping

Sample data

```
Name: test
id   age
1    25
2    48
3    77
4    17
5    27
```

I wanted to add a new column called `age_group` so I added:

```
test$age_group<-NA
```

In this new column I wanted to add a group (obviously) by age.

```
<18=1
19-30=2 
31-45=3
46-60=4
61-75=5
>76 = 6
```

so the data would now look like this:

```
id   age  age_group
1    25   2
2    48   4
3    77   6
4    17   1
5    27   2
```

Can someone help with the code on how to populate `age_group`?

Comment: You'll want to look into `cut()`

Comment: age_group[test$age > 0 & test$age <=18] <- 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df$age_group <- cut(df$age, breaks = c(0,18,30,45,60,75,Inf), labels = 1:6)

#  id age age_group
#1  1  25         2
#2  2  48         4
#3  3  77         6
#4  4  17         1
#5  5  27         2
```

Comment: Error in cut.default(df$age_group, breaks = c(0,18,30,45,60,75,Inf 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: @laura why this `cut.default(df$age_group, ...)`?? its not what I answered. You do not need to create the column `age_group` beforehand. When you assign the result of the `cut`, the column will be created automatically. You get the error probably because `df$age_group` is all `NA`. Please note that the first argument of the `cut` is `df$age`!

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I went in and deleted age_group, redid the code and still got that error :-/

Comment: @laura If you can paste the first 6 rows of your real data, then I can have a look what can be the cause. Otherwise, based on your given data, every thing is fine and you see the result posted in my answer.

Comment: Ok well in all fairness, I was really working on income from the census. I picked age just to make it simpler:

Comment: `geoid                                    name income income_error`
`1 15000US110010001001 Block Group 1, District of Columbia, DC 142279        88319`
`2 15000US110010001002 Block Group 2, District of Columbia, DC 121648        36954`
`3 15000US110010001003 Block Group 3, District of Columbia, DC 213750        61904`
`4 15000US110010001004 Block Group 4, District of Columbia, DC 241314        46452`
`5 15000US110010002011 Block Group 1, District of Columbia, DC      0            0`
`6 15000US110010002021 Block Group 1, District of Columbia, DC 185000        58857`

Comment: You should use `dput(head(df))` to provide someone with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another efficient option with `findInterval`

```
findInterval(test$age, c(0, 18, 30,45, 60, 75, Inf))
#[1] 2 4 6 1 2
```